# Ionic checkbox not auto checked

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

first I have checkbox code like this, and the checkbox can auto checked

```
<ion-checkbox color="dark" checked="true">
```

but after I add the ngModel, why the checkbox cannot auto checked?

```
<ion-checkbox color="dark" checked="true" [(ngModel)]="data.remember">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ion-checkbox color="dark" checked="true" [(ngModel)]="data.remember">
```

just assign your ngModel variable to true

```
this.data.remember = true;
```